# Small `vector`-like structure with no capacity distinct from size

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures

I have a program where I have very large number (hundreds of thousands, even millions) of fairly small vectors (~95% of these vectors contain 2-6 `int`s). Once created, their size changes very rarely, but cannot be known at compile time. I have no use for extra capacity beyond the size of the structure, and I'd like to do away with the overhead of storing the capacity separately. This would entail reallocation of storage for any operation that changes the size of the structure, a cost I'm willing to pay.

Does a library providing a more or less drop-in replacement for `vector` with these characteristics exist?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit looking for this?

Comment: You could always roll your own with a kind of arena-style allocator.

Comment: You might consider using [`boost::container::small_vector`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost/container/small_vector.html). It reduces memory allocations and improves data locality.

Comment: You could have one huge vector storing all the data and another large vector of `std::span<int>` (or maybe `std::pair<int*, int*>`) referencing the individual *sub-vectors*.

Comment: @김선달 Using `shrink_to_fit` could (not definitely) eliminate the unused capacity, but it would not remove the need to store the capacity in the `vector` object.

Comment: @Galik - something like what you propose is certainly something I've thought of, but it would require some fairly substantial rearchitecting. I would prefer a drop-in replacement that I could compile the application with to test if it has any impact on performance before any such undertaking.

Answer (score 3):

Folly "*is a library of C++14 components designed with practicality and efficiency in mind. Folly contains a variety of core library components used extensively at Facebook*"

[Folly smallvec](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/small_vector.md) is an optimized implementation of a small vector.
Give it a look.

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating each vector individually? If so have you tried using arrays instead? You could do a quick size check(how many ints you're putting in the array) before creating, that way you don't have to have extra capacity. Also, 김선달's comment above sounds like what you're looking for.